# Open a program as Admin on Windows 7 with no prompt?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I'm having this problem with two programs: Visual Studio 2008 and Notepad++.

If I'm making a webpage and I add a debugger statement to the javascript, it opens up a prompt asking me if I want to debug. If I then click "new instance of VS2008", it will try to open it but fail and give me an error message. I think it's failing because I have the "Run as Administrator" checked and it couldn't prompt me when I open it like that. If I open it through windows it works.

In Notepad++ the problem comes from the context menu "Open in Notepad++"

Comment: Disable UAC when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the shortcut to VS2008 and Notepad++ go to Properties > Advanced then check the box always run as administrator.

That should work, I had a similar problem with Wireshark

Comment: Scrap that, I mis-read your question!!

Comment: Don't feel too bad. I know the excitement of answering a question based on the title and then going back to delete it after reading the details. Often, the title is not worded correctly to describe the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've never run into a situation with Visual Studio 2008-2010 where it needs to run as administrator for basic local debugging... that is true for web application and javascript debugging as well. It might be something else?

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, I shouldn't be trying to run it as administrator. I should be giving the account it's running under access to whatever files I need.